# Install packages resulted in reboot/shutdown freeze

Tags: shutdown, reboot

I have installed a brand new 12.04 on my Dell XPS M1330 laptop. Initially, it is able to reboot/shutdown normally. However, after I installed my first software, ubuntu-tweak, my laptop was frozen in the reboot/shutdown process consistently, result in a black screen.

Because of my suspicion, I remove and purge ubuntu-tweak, then try again. It worked this time! It is obvious that ubuntu-tweak cause this power manager problem on my laptop.

However, I have encountered another reboot/shutdown freeze after I started to install most of popular programs in the Ubuntu Software Center. I have been force logout during the installation. After that, my laptop have the reboot/shutdown freeze constantly!

I am wondering what kind of bug would cause this problem and how to resolve it. Any idea?

Comment: is your system up-to-date?

Comment: Yes, I update it after my installation. It can be rebooted or shutdown normally then. However, after I installed ubuntu-tweak and some other packages, I have those problem. Now I have to shutdown my laptop by push power button for 5 seconds.....every time!

Comment: is Ubuntu 12.04 your first Linux distribution, did you use some other distributions, or maybe an older version of Ubuntu. If so, tell me whether the problem was present in those distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, my laptop will rebooted and shutdown normally, but I found that turn on the bluetooth could solve this problem.

I have turned off bluetooth via system tray icon after my installation, since I never use it. Therefore it was hard to discover that this action will affect the power management. Today my laptop may be reboot and shutdown normally but unexpectedly, because, for some unknown reasons, my bluetooth has been turned on without intention.

I have turned it on and off several times to experiment, and it turns out that when my bluetooth is off it is the causing my laptop to freeze, it results in a black screen during a reboot or shutdown. Only if I turn on bluetooth in system settings, my laptop boots.

For anyone who has the same power management issue on your laptop, try your bluetooth first!